# Not able to filter data as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

```
this.prepData.filter(e=>e.workflowRoleDesc!=s)[1].userList.filter(e=>e.value != filteredData.map(e=>e.userId))
```

`this.prepData` basically looks like this, inside `userList` we have another array which has a field called value.

```
0: {workflowRoleDesc: 'Preparer', userList: Array(61), isRoleEnable: true}
1: {workflowRoleDesc: 'Reviewer', userList: Array(44), isRoleEnable: true}
2: {workflowRoleDesc: 'Approver', userList: Array(49), isRoleEnable: true}
```

length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

`s` is string variable which can have one of the following value at a time `Preparer`, `Reviewer` or `Approver`.

and

```
filteredData.map(e=>e.userId)
(2) ['86cb7ae5-2b56-4437-af5a-115018d69403', '188e20db-db56-41c9-9bfa-20c7d02b4da0']
```

In the second filter when I am using `filteredData.map(e=>e.userId)`, it does not filter anything but if I give the value '86cb7ae5-2b56-4437-af5a-115018d69403' directly it is working as expected.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are comparing a `value` (which seems to be a string) with an array of strings `filteredData.map(e=>e.userId)`. Maybe you should use:

```
this.prepData
  .filter(e=>e.workflowRoleDesc!=s)[1]
    .userList.filter(e=>filteredData.map(e=>e.userId).indexOf(e.value) < 0)
```

Meaning that you want to use the users that are NOT among the `filteredData` ones.